# What is the evaluation order of the expression &x->y->z?

Tags: c

Suppose you have a C line of code `&x->y->z` (doesn't matter what the x/y/z's are). What is the order of evaluation here? I see that `->` takes precedence over `&` in https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence. So is this evaluation sequence correct?

1. `x->y` is evaluated, and with that result
2. `(x->y)->z` is evaluated, and with that result
3. `&((x->y)->z)` is evaluated

If this is incorrect, can you tell me what the correct order is?

Comment: Note that `(x->y)->z` is evaluated only to determine the object that is member `z`. Its value is not retrieved; it is not needed since the expression is taking the address of this object, not using its value.

Comment: Thank you. What you pointed out is the reason I asked this question, because there is something here I don't understand: as you said, the expression is taking the address of this object, so the value of `z` is not needed. But how does the program know that at step 2, where it is evaluating `(x->y)->z`, since we are taking the address only at step 3? To be sure, if we have `x->y->z`, the value of `z` is retrieved. So how does the program know not to retrieve the value of `z` in `&x->y->z`?

Comment: @Min because "order of operations" doesn't imply an absolute order of information flow. The compiler has already read all of the code before anything starts running. When it decides what code to emit for the `->z` it *knows* that what it's compiling is an operand of `&` and can act accordingly.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "precedence" doesn't mean order of evaluation . It refers to the association of operands with operators.  For example in `f() + g() * h()`, the three function calls could occur in any order; saying that `*` has higher precedence is saying that the two operands of `*` are `g()` and `h()`.  The compiler might call all three functions, and then multiply the results of the `g` and `h` calls, and then add the result of the `f` call.

In `&x->y->z` things are easier because the second operand of `->` (and `.`) isn't an expression. It's an identifier that names a class member. So the second operand isn't evaluated, really.

The precedence rules, or grammar table, tells use that the operand of the unary `&` operator is `x->y->z`.

To understand `x->y->z`, clearly it is not the case that we are looking for a member of the struct pointed to by `x` whose name is "`y->z`" since that is not a valid identifier.  That would not be a valid syntax parse. So it can only mean that `->z` is applied to the result of `x->y`.

Answer (score 2):

You are right this is the correct order. explination below:

**&x->y->z**

if we look in your expression above no matter what is x,y and z. we see that its contained from arrow `->` operators or more technicaly speeking (`Structure and union member access through pointer`) and the address operator `&`.

In c programing there is the precedence and associativity for all operators. when we come to expression that we have 2 operators with the same precedence then we need to look at the associativity inorder to know what expression we need to evaluate first.

your expression have 2 `->` operators and one `&` operator. `->` operator is in the higest (precedence 1) precedence group of operators (he is not alone in this group see the table below). and `&` in the second higest group (precedence 2) and he is not alone in this group. so operator  `->` must be evaluated first. but where to start? here comes the associativity. for group 1 in the table below, we evaluates from left to right.

SO the order of the evaluation is:

1. `x->y` : evaluate first. for example lets assume its evaluates to `P`. (x->y=P)
2. `P->z` OR `(x->y)->z`: evaluates after the first (we are going from left to right folowing the associativity rule).
3. `&((x->y)->z)` : only now we evaluate the `&` operator and this will be the final result.

see the link below for [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are exactly correct.

The `->` operator has the highest precedence and groups from left to right.  So that gives you `&((x->y)->z)`.